# LinearLayout not displaying images added programmatically

Tags: java, android, arraylist, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a line of hearts indicating the number of lives the player currently has. This is my code:

LifeGraphics.java

```
public class LifeGraphics {
    public static ArrayList<ImageView> getLiast(Context context){
        ImageView life1 = new ImageView(context);
        life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
        ImageView life2 = new ImageView(context);
        life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
        ImageView life3 = new ImageView(context);
        life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
        ImageView life4 = new ImageView(context);
        life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
        ImageView life5 = new ImageView(context);
        life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
        ImageView[] inRetrunList = new ImageView[] {life1, life2, life3, life4, life5};
        ArrayList<ImageView> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        returnList.addAll(Arrays.asList(inRetrunList));
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

GameActivity.java (Excerpt):

```
ArrayList<ImageView> livesGraphicsList = LifeGraphics.getLiast(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
for(int i = 0; i < lives; i++){
    layout.addView(livesGraphicsList.get(i), (i + 1));
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Only one heart is shown]

When they lose a life the number goes down properly and the image goes away after the last life. also logging the layout.getChildCount() gives me 6 (the textview and the 5 added imageView i guess). Can someone please explain why the are not showing on screen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the image only to the first ImageView. To be more precise you set it 5 times.

```
    ImageView life1 = new ImageView(context);
    life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);
    ImageView life2 = new ImageView(context);
    life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart); //Should be life2
    ImageView life3 = new ImageView(context);
    life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);//Should be life3
    ImageView life4 = new ImageView(context);
    life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);//Should be life4
    ImageView life5 = new ImageView(context);
    life1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heart);//Should be life5
```

Comment: Thank you i did not see that. I will accept answer when it lets me. I owe you one FINDarkside